Chrome returns net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED
I have the following use case:

I upload a document to my Angular app
The Angular app, opens a new Chrome tab and sends a message using window.postMessage() containing the file and some other data
The target Angular app, listens for the message and makes an HTTP POST request to some service hosted in yet another host with the file

Problem:

Everything works fine when the origin app is the same origin as the target. But when the origin defers from the target, the HTTP POST fails with: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Investigations done:

I tried it on Safari and everything works even when the origin differs
Added the following response headers to the target SPA:

Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: unsafe-none
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: unsafe-none
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin


I logged a message in the console before firing the HTTP Request, there is no error. This ensures that the target accesses the file sent by the source.

Any idea?

It's a long-shot but maybe try Firefox and see if you get a more informative error message. I was getting net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED in Chrome but Firefox said NS_ERROR_FILE_IS_DIRECTORY i.e. why the access was actually denied, not just that it had been denied.
